# Define $f : X \rightarrow Y$ by $f(x) = y_0$ for every $x \in X$. Then $f$ is $\mathfrak T_1 - \mathfrak T_2$ continuous.

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose that $(X, \mathfrak T_1)$ and $(Y, \mathfrak T_2)$ are topological spaces and suppose $y_0 \in Y$.  Define $f : X \rightarrow Y$ by $f(x) = y_0$ for every $x \in X$.  Then $f$ is $\mathfrak T_1 - \mathfrak T_2$ continuous.

My definitions for continuous are as follows:
A function $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is said to be continuous if for each open subset $V$ of $\mathbb R$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$

A function $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continous (by the above definition) iff for each $x_0 \in \mathbb R$, given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\varphi \gt 0$ such that $|x-x_0| \lt \varphi \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0) |\lt \varepsilon$.

I would love some direction on how to go about doing this. I have pondered this and really have no clue where to go with the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Either $V$ contains $y_0$ or it doesn't. If it does then what is $f^{-1}(V)?$ Why is it open? (Recall the axioms of a topology...) Similarly for if $V$ doesn't contain $y_0.$

Comment: Does $f^{-1}(V) = X$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U\subseteq Y$ be open.  Either $y_0\in U$ or not.  If $y_0\in U$, then $f^{-1}(U)=X$ is open in $X$.  Otherwise $f^{-1}(U)=\phi$ is open in $X$.  As $U\subseteq Y$ was arbitrary we have that $f$ is continuous by definition.